# How to write Rising edge counter in C

Tags: c

Could you please give me some sgueestios about how to write the the rising edge counter in C?
becuase I don't have idea how to detect the rising edge, so I don't know how to do it.

the figure is what I want to do, there are four pulses in the figure, and I want to detect each one.
and using counter to let me know there are total four pulse in there.

[image]

I would like know how to do it.
amy idea could help me are very good to me.
I am very appreciate, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Process the samples from left to right, and if a certain number of consecutive samples exceed a threshold A, you have detected a rising edge.

After this, you detect a falling edge by finding a certain number of consecutive samples that are below another threshold B.

The thresholds should be such that A > B.

Only after the falling edge has been detected can you detect another rising edge.